# Matlab - slice 3D volume

Tags: matlab, 3d, slice

I need to slice a 3D volume (200x200x500 matrix) and plot the result. I tried following the example from Mathworks reported [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/exploring-volumes-with-slice-planes.html?refresh=true), but the resulting slice is empty (it shouldn't be)... Do you have suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Here is the code I am using and the resulting slice:

```
xmin = 1;
ymin = 1;
zmin = 1;
xmax = 200;
ymax = 200;
zmax = 499;
hslice = surf(linspace(xmin,xmax,100),...
              linspace(ymin,ymax,100),...
              zeros(100));
rotate(hslice,[100,100,250],-45)
xd = get(hslice,'XData');
yd = get(hslice,'YData');
zd = get(hslice,'ZData');
delete(hslice);
x = 1:200;
y = 1:200;
z = 1:499;
figure;
colormap(jet);
h = slice(x,y,z,V1,xd,yd,zd);
h.FaceColor = 'interp';
h.EdgeColor = 'none';
h.DiffuseStrength = 0.8;
```

[image]

Comment: Could explain your code? What does V1 stand for? It would be nice if the code was executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will draw a slice at x=100

```
v=randn(200,200,500);
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:200,1:200,1:500);
h=slice(x,y,z,v,100,[],[]);
set(h,'EdgeColor','none')
```

like wise you can place additional slices at y or z if you replace the [] with coordinates for e.h. y and z.